# o que significa tirar férias?

Tags: significado, gramática

Eu sei que por exemplo

> você tira férias.

significa:

> you are on holiday.

Agora a pergunta é: o que significa a expressão "tirar férias", sozinha?

Por exemplo em:

> Quanto tempo posso tirar férias?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Tirar férias* refere-se ao ato de interromper determinada atividade para descanso (férias).

> Já não posso *tirar férias* este ano, já gastei os dias todos a que tinha direito.
>   O meu patrão obriga-me a *tirar férias* em agosto.

Por extensão, pode dizer-se *preciso de tirar férias da minha esposa*, por exemplo (i.e., preciso de estar afastado dela por uns tempos). Ou ainda (exemplo do CETEMPúblico):

> «Não contem comigo para tirar férias das minhas responsabilidades, só porque hoje é véspera da véspera do que quer que seja, por importante que seja»

*Tirar férias* não se refere apenas ao ponto em que as férias começam, inclui também a duração do descanso. Na frase seguinte, o significado é muito semelhante a *passar férias (em algum lado)*:

> Muita gente *tira/passa férias* no Algarve.

---

Agora para os exemplos que dás:

> Você tira férias.

Esta frase não significa *you are on holiday*. Na verdade, isoladamente, esta frase não faz sentido, devido a restrições aspectuais do Presente. Poderias usar o presente com uma leitura habitual se indicasses a frequência ou a duração:

> Você **tira férias** *todos os semestres*.
>   Você **tira férias** *longas*.

Outro contexto em que o Presente é aceitável é se se tratar de um plano estabelecido no presente:

> Fazemos assim: você tira férias e volta só quando estiver recuperado.

Para *he's on holiday*, dirias *ele está de férias*.

---

A tua última frase:

> Quanto tempo posso tirar férias?

Esta frase também me parece duvidosa. Poderias dizer (com o mesmo significado):

> Durante quanto tempo posso tirar férias?
>   Posso tirar férias de quanto tempo? / Quanto tempo posso tirar de férias? / Quanto tempo de férias posso tirar?

O significado é o mesmo que expliquei no início. *Tirar férias* tem uma duração implícita, e estas perguntas referem-se a essa duração.

Comment: Bem explicado..